# Init NSViewController without nib

Tags: macos, swift, nsview, nib, nsviewcontroller

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334583/4107801

I tried the method mentioned in this answer but it crashes with bad access every time.

Maybe the private APIs have changed or I'm simply implementing it incorrectly. Here is my implementation:

```
override func loadView() {
    view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
    //view = self.view
    splitView = NSSplitView(frame: view.frame)
    splitView?.autoresizingMask = .ViewWidthSizable | .ViewHeightSizable
    splitView?.setPosition(300, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
    view.addSubview(splitView!)
}
```

Comment: what is the crash? what is your view variable?

Answer (score 1):

LoadView doesn't init the contentView in the controller so you have to do that manually too.

Adding

```
view = NSView(frame:CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)))
```

solved the problem.